# Enquiry about Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi i am new to selenium webdriver testing. We have a test project at our company and i am trying to understand the basics. I know a little bit to help me code simple test. I want to know if there are any possibilities to have two group names for one test like

@Test(groups = {"group1", "group2"})

and make the test work by including group1 in one suite and group2 in another suite, also is there multiple dependency groupings like

dependsOnGroups = {"group1", "group2"}

i am trying to understand the framework so any comments is welcome, but pleasr try to keep it simple. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, WebDriver does not have that kind of feature. If I understand your problem correctly, you need to use unit testing framework. What language are you using to code tests with webdriver? If java, I reccomend using [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/) - check out documentation and search web a little, you are probably interested in topic of Test Suites, which are used to grouping tests.